# getDatabase called recursively Kotlin Android

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

I get the error when the following is executed. I send a DAO to `populateDatabase` but it is just giving me the error and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
companion object {

        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: LoanHubDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context, scope: CoroutineScope): LoanHubDatabase {
            val tempInstance = INSTANCE
            if (tempInstance != null) {
                return tempInstance
            }

            synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    LoanHubDatabase::class.java,
                    "LoanHub_Database"
                ).addCallback(UserDatabaseCallback(scope))
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                return instance
            }

        }

    } 


private class UserDatabaseCallback(private val scope: CoroutineScope) :
        RoomDatabase.Callback() {

        @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        override fun onOpen(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            super.onOpen(db)
            INSTANCE?.let { database ->
                scope.launch {(Dispatchers.IO)
                    populateDatabase(database.LoanDao())
                }

            }
        }

        @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        suspend fun populateDatabase(loanDao: LoanDao)  {

            val loan = Loan(0, "Sagicor", "Ready Loan", 800000, 8.0, "70 months", 100.00,70, "The ready loan is the best loan", "Women","Active", "2020-01-01")
            loanDao.addNewLoan(loan)

        }
```

The error which I received is:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getDatabase called recursively
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:357)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:317)
        at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:92)
        at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:53)
        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.inTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:476)
        at androidx.room.CoroutinesRoom$Companion.execute(CoroutinesRoom.kt:45)
        at androidx.room.CoroutinesRoom.execute(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.uwi.loanhub.models.LoanDao_Impl.addNewLoan(LoanDao_Impl.java:95)
```

Comment: i think you are trying to write before you have created the database. share your INSTANCE variable code as well.

Comment: @sadat updated with the code you requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try replacing your onOpen method with onCreate

From

```
override fun onOpen(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            super.onOpen(db)
//rest of your code
}
```

To

```
override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                    super.onCreate(db)
//rest of your code
}
```

Comment: as I said earlier, you were trying to write on the database before you create. Now if the database is not created, it will call onCreate and then the loop happens again. If it works, you may accept the answer as correct. Thanks

Comment: So where do I put the ```populateDatabase``` function?

Comment: if you had replaced your onOpen with onCreate. it should be alright.

Comment: I did but the function ```populateDatabase``` is not being called.